# How does Java stores float value

Tags: java, floating-point

In JVM float value stores in binary system. But how it exactly stored?
In example.

```
int value = Math.pow(10,8) + 1;

float f = value;

int back = (int)f;
```

back value is equal to 10^8.
Where is 1

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.1

Comment: You should read IEEE 758 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: Do study the 3 links above. As near as dammit is to swearing, a `float` can only store 7 significant figures of data. Hence `1` is not significant in a number with magnitude 10e8. As for how it's stored, study the first link.